# Can I avoid CSS glitch due to clip-path and transition on the same element on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, clip-path

I have been fooling around with the CSS clip-path property, and creative ways to style a button element. My HTML and CSS are as follows:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px;
}

button {
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
/*   box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 15%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 85%, 0 100%);
  transition: 0.55s;
  padding-right: 220px;
}

button:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(0 15%, 49% 0, 49% 50%, 51% 50%, 51% 0, 100% 15%, 100% 85%, 51% 100%, 51% 50%, 49% 50%, 49% 100%, 0 85%);
  background-color: #bb0000;
  transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  padding-right: initial;
  padding-left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<button>Contact<br>Us</button>
```

I've also created a codepen which can be found here:
https://codepen.io/kosakk/pen/JjeXPJX

My question is, is there a way to prevent it from glitching when the rotation occurs and the mouse pointer happens to be over the background during the transition? Or is this just the way it has to be, and I'd have to alter my clip-path somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: if you want to apply a rotation on hover always add the hover on a parent element and not the element you want to rotate

Comment: How should I apply the rotation, custom text padding, and clip-path changes to the button if I target a parent element though? I don't want to only rotate it 360 degrees.

Comment: `.someparent:hover button { /* do stuff here */ }`

Comment: The reason you get this behaviour is because on hover the rotation starts, and a frame later your mouse is now on a piece of the clipped path that has no content, so it's no longer hovering etc... As said, make a parent box the target for the hover but not the transformation, then you can be sure the cursor is still on the parent as it's bounds aren't going to change.

Comment: It is getting better - indeed - but there is still room for improvement. If I hover a little over the transformed button, the glitch persists. It just doesn't happen when hovering on top of the button in its initial state.